# SpringBootTests using WithSecurityContextFactory failing every second time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-security, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.5 application with Vaadin. In order to run UI tests I mock a user using WithSecurityContextFactory and a custom annotation.

This annotation is used in many classes and works without issue. Except in two classes: They use the same annotation as all the others but fail on every second run, when running gradle build or just the test task. It's extremely odd behvaiour but I was able to replicate it many, many times. When I just run the test class itself it never fails.

The reason the tests fail is because the SecurityContext is empty. The question though is why? I can't find a single reason, the configuration of the test classes is the exact same as every other test class. This is one of the failing classes:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration
public class ParticipantAdminFormViewTest {

    private static Routes routes;
    @Mock
    private ParticipantAdminService participantAdminService;
    private final Mandant mandant = TestUtils.createMandant();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void createRoutes() {
    // initialize routes only once, to avoid view auto-detection before every test
    // and to speed up the tests
    routes = new Routes().autoDiscoverViews("package.to.view.classes");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupVaadin() {
    MockVaadin.setup(routes);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDownVaadin() {
    MockVaadin.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockCustomUser
    void testCreateView() {
    //test
    }
```

The annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithMockCustomUser {

    String[] roles() default {};

}
```

And finally the SecurityContextFactory:

```
public class WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithMockCustomUser> {
    private final static String ID_TOKEN = "omitted for brevity";

    @Override
    public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithMockCustomUser annotation) {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (var role : annotation.roles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("roles", annotation.roles());
    claims.put("sub", 123);
    OidcIdToken idToken = new OidcIdToken(ID_TOKEN, null, null, claims);
    var participant = createParticipant();
    CustomOidcUser principal = new CustomEmployeeOidcUser(authorities, idToken, participant, createAccount(participant),createMandant(), createEmployee());
    Authentication auth = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(principal, principal.getAuthorities(), "test");
    context.setAuthentication(auth);
    return context;
    }

    private Employee createEmployee() {
    var employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstName("Test");
    employee.setLastName("Employee");
    employee.setId(1L);
    return employee;
    }

    private Mandant createMandant() {
    var mandant = new Mandant();
    mandant.setId(1L);
    mandant.setName("Test Mandant");
    return mandant;
    }

    private Account createAccount(Participant participant) {
    var account = new Account();
    account.setUsername("test.user@email.com");
    account.setPersonFl(Boolean.TRUE);
    account.setParticipant(participant);
    return account;
    }

    private Participant createParticipant() {
    var participant = new Participant();
    participant.setId(1L);
    participant.setFirstName("Test");
    participant.setLastName("User");
    participant.setEmail("test.user@email.com");
    return participant;
    }
}
```

Tried to find any triggers that might cause this. Expected the SecurityContext to be present and therefore the tests to pass.